# If I close a ServerSocket, will the Sockets accepted by the ServerSocket be also closed?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(some_port);
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
serverSocket.close();
```

Will `socket` be closed as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Accepted `Sockets` are completely independent of the `ServerSocket` they were accepted from.